# Victory v. Biscuit malt

Tags: beer, flavor, ingredients

Are there flavor differences between these two malts?
How can each be described?
I have used them both but often in complicated recipes, and never side by side for comparison.
How is each produced?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Victory has a more nutty flavor than Biscuit malt and gives more of an orange color to beer. They're both lightly roasted malts with biscuit flavors though, so the differences can be subtle